# Spring amqp converter issue using rabbit listener

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I think I am missing something here..I am trying to create simple rabbit listner which can accept custom object as message type. Now as per doc it says

*In versions prior to 1.6, the type information to convert the JSON had to be provided in message headers, or a custom ClassMapper was required. Starting with version 1.6, if there are no type information headers, the type can be inferred from the target method arguments.*

I am putting message manually in to queue using rabbit mq adm in dashboard,getting error like

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [com.example.Customer] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[21], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=customer, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=customer, amqp_redelivered=false, id=81e8a562-71aa-b430-df03-f60e6a37c5dc, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-LQARUDrR6sUcn7FqAKKVDA, timestamp=1485635555742}]
```

My configuration:

```
@Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new    CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("test");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("test1234");
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("/");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
        return rabbitAdmin;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
```

Also question is with this exception message is not put back in the queue.

I am using spring boot 1.4 which brings amqp 1.6.1.

Edit1 : I added jackson converter as above (prob not required with spring boot) and given contenty type on rmq admin but still got below, as you can see above I am not configuring any listener container yet.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [com.example.Customer] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[21], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=customer, content_type=application/json, amqp_deliveryTag=3, amqp_consumerQueue=customer, amqp_redelivered=false, id=7f84d49d-037a-9ea3-e936-ed5552d9f535, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-YSemzbIW6Q8JGYUS70WWtA, timestamp=1485643437271}]
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you are using boot, you can simply add a `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` `@Bean` to the configuration and it will be automatically wired into the listener (as long as it's the only converter). You need to set the  `content_type` property to `application/json` if you are using the administration console to send the message.

Conversion errors are considered fatal by default because there is generally no reason to retry; otherwise they'd loop for ever.

**EDIT**

Here's a working boot app...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So41914665Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So41914665Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("foo", false, false, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public void listen(Foo foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }


    public static class Foo {

        public String bar;

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

I sent this message

[image: Publish json message]

With this result:

```
2017-01-28 21:49:45.509  INFO 11453 --- [           main] com.example.So41914665Application        : Started So41914665Application in 4.404 seconds (JVM running for 5.298)
Foo [bar=baz]
```

Boot will define an admin and template for you.

Comment: here you go - https://github.com/stackspring/sample . This will be best to identify issue. Pull that and give a try.

Comment: You need to add `@Configuration` to your `RabbitConfig` class - boot does not see the converter bean and therefore doesn't wire it in. BTW, you don't need admin and template beans; boot's autoconfig will add them for you. You also don't need a `ConnectionFactory`; you can put your credentials in application.yml (or .properties). See the [boot reference documentation about RabbitMQ auto configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-rabbitmq). Your sample works for me when I added `@Configuration`. I'd also recommend upgrading to 1.4.4.

Comment: Extremely sorry for wasting your time :(. I should have paid more attention. I will do double checking before posting next time. Ya I dont need those beans just for what I did, but I am planning to experiment few more things on this.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue, turns out that, git stash/merge messed up with my config, I need to include this package again in my main again:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "com.example.amqp"  // <- git merge messed this up
})
public class TeamActivityApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TeamActivityApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```